# Custom output wsdl nusoap

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I using NuSoap/PHP and I want to do a custom output

I want my output be like so:

```
            <xsd:element name="crearCentro">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="entsal:DATOS_IDENTIFICATIVOS"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="crearCentroResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="salida:RESPUESTA_DATOS_CENTRO"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
```

And i getting that:

```
<xsd:complexType name="crearCentro"/>
<xsd:element name="crearCentro" type="tns:crearCentro"/>
```

I have this and I don't know how I should do:

```
$server->wsdl->addElement(array('name' => 'crearCentro','type'=>'crearCentro' ));
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'crearCentro',
'sequence',
'struct',
'all');
```

Thanks!

Comment: <xsd:element name="crearCentro">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="entsal:DATOS_IDENTIFICATIVOS"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>  It means tag name "crearCentro" is unbound. create xml in loop

Comment: thanks for be so fast, but i won't this, i want the PHP code because i don't know create an element within a sequence within a complextype

Comment: you have to  create xml from php code within loop as per your tag. like tag name "crearCentro" is unbound so have to create a xml from php code via  loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$servicio->wsdl->addComplexType('Item', 
                                'complexType', 
                                'array', 
                                'sequence', 
                                '',
                                array('Placa' => array('name' => 'Placa','type' => 'xs:string'),
                                'cantidadItem' => array('name' => 'cantidadItem','type' => 'xs:decimal'),
                                'codigoProducto' => array('name' => 'codigoProducto','type' => 'xs:int'),
                                'descripcionItem' => array('name' => 'descripcionItem','type' => 'xs:string'),
                                'descuentoItem' => array('name' => 'descuentoItem','type' => 'xs:decimal'),
                                'igvItem' => array('name' => 'igvItem','type' => 'xs:decimal'),
                                'importe' => array('name' => 'importe','type' => 'xs:decimal'),
                                'monto' => array('name' => 'monto','type' => 'xs:decimal'),
                                'numeroItem' => array('name' => 'numeroItem','type' => 'xs:long'),
                                'precioUnitario' => array('name' => 'precioUnitario','type' => 'xs:decimal'),
                                'tipoOperacion' => array('name' => 'tipoOperacion','type' => 'xs:int'),
                                'unidadItem' => array('name' => 'unidadItem','type' => 'xs:string'),
                                'valor' => array('name' => 'valor','type' => 'xs:decimal'),
                                'valorUnitario' => array('name' => 'valorUnitario','type' => 'xs:decimal')
                                  )
);
```

Comment: Please format the answer and be descriptive with the answer.